# How to display integers without exponential values (eg:income>29e+3) in the dendlogram using rpart.plot?

Tags: r

How to display integers without exponential values (eg:income>29e+3) in the dendlogram using rpart.plot ?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to give some sample data. Also, please share the code you are using to generate the plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide specific details, I will take a shot with a toy dataset -

**Solution**

```
library("rpart.plot")
anova.model <- rpart(Mileage ∼ ., data=cu.summary)
rpart.plot(anova.model, digits=-1)
```

[image]

If you do not use `digits=-1`, this is what you get -

```
library("rpart.plot")
anova.model <- rpart(Mileage ∼ ., data=cu.summary)
rpart.plot(anova.model)
```

[image]

Notice the difference in the `Price` variable values.

**Why?**

If you browse through the [`rpart.plot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart.plot/rpart.plot.pdf) documentation -

> digits The number of significant digits in displayed numbers. Default
>   2. If 0, use getOption("digits"). **If negative, use the standard format function (with the absolute value of digits)**. When digits is positive,
>   the following details apply: Numbers from 0.001 to 9999 are printed
>   without an exponent (and the number of digits is actually only a
>   suggestion, see format for details). Numbers out that range are
>   printed with an “engineering” exponent (a multiple of 3).

Comment: Good answer.  Another trick is to divide variables like Price by 1000 before building the model, i.e. modify the data before calling rpart, so Price is in kilo-dollars instead of in dollars.